# How to handle space in recipient address

Tags: ibm-domino

I am trying to send email using *NodeMailer* Node module and IBM Domino server. 
I need to send email to a recipient  `Domino Administrator/test@test` but the space in address creates issue.

Because of space in address, Server return error as it considers recipient as `Administrator/test@test` which does not exists.

> Router: Unable to deliver message 0023B889 to Administrator/test@test.

I tried adding ascii characters for space, tried surrounding by extra quotes but nothing worked.

I am initializing mail options in Nodemailer like this

```
var mailOptions = {
  from: 'Domino Administrator/test',
  to: 'Domino Administrator/test@test',
  subject: 'Sending mail domino 2',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};
```

Any idea how to handle space ? or any changes needs to be done at Domino server side ?

Answer (score 0):

Taking hint from some RFC , I was able to sort this issue by adding '_'. So the code works if recipient address is to: 'Domino_Administrator/test@test'